# Is avoiding expensive __init__ a good reason to use __new__?

Tags: python, class

In my project, we have a class based on set. It can be initialised from a string, or an iterable (eg tuple) of strings, or other custom classes. When initialised with an iterable it converts each item to a particular custom class if it is not one already.

Because it can be initialised from a variety of data structures a lot of the methods that operate on this class (such as `__and__`) are liberal in what they accept and just convert their arguments to this class (ie initialise a new instance). We are finding this is rather slow, when the argument is already an instance of the class, and has a lot of members (it is iterating through them all and checking that they are the right type).

I was thinking that to avoid this, we could add a `__new__` method to the class and just if the argument passed in is already an instance of the class, return it directly. Would this be a reasonable use of `__new__`?

Comment: How about modifying `__and__` to check `if isinstance(obj, CustomClass)`? and handle this common case without calling `CustomClass(obj)`?

Comment: @unutbu yes, that was the first idea, but it turns out there are lots of places where CustomClass is just initialised without checking. Nonetheless that's probably what the right answer is, to add `isinstance` checks to most of those places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Adding* a `__new__` method will not solve your problem. From the documentation for [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> **If `__new__()` returns an instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s
>   `__init__()` method will be invoked** like `__init__(self[, ...])`,
>   where `self` is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the
>   same as were passed to `__new__()`.

In otherwords, returning the same instance will *not* prevent python from calling `__init__`.
You can verify this quite easily:

```
In [20]: class A:
    ...:     def __new__(cls, arg):
    ...:         if isinstance(arg, cls):
    ...:             print('here')
    ...:             return arg
    ...:         return super().__new__(cls)
    ...:     def __init__(self, values):
    ...:         self.values = list(values)

In [21]: a = A([1,2,3])

In [22]: A(a)
here
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-c206e38274e0> in <module>()
----> 1 A(a)

<ipython-input-20-5a7322f37287> in __init__(self, values)
      6         return super().__new__(cls)
      7     def __init__(self, values):
----> 8         self.values = list(values)

TypeError: 'A' object is not iterable
```

You *may* be able to make this work if you did *not* implement `__init__` at all, but only `__new__`. I believe this is what `tuple` does.

Also that behaviour would be acceptable only if your class is immutable (e.g. `tuple` does this), because the result would be sensible. If it is mutable you are asking for hidden bugs.

A more sensible approach is to do what `set` does: `__*__` operations operate *only* on `set`s, however `set` also provides named methods that work with any iterable:

```
In [30]: set([1,2,3]) & [1,2]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-dfd866b6c99b> in <module>()
----> 1 set([1,2,3]) & [1,2]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'list'

In [31]: set([1,2,3]) & set([1,2])
Out[31]: {1, 2}

In [32]: set([1,2,3]).intersection([1,2])
Out[32]: {1, 2}
```

In this way the user can choose between speed and flexibility of the API.

---

A simpler approach is the one proposed by unutbu: use `isinstance` instead of duck-typing when implementing the operations.

Comment: Great, thanks so much. I didn't read the docs closely enough. Why do you say "If it is mutable you are asking for hidden bugs"?

Comment: Also that's a really interesting point about set, I never realised that subtle difference before, but it makes sense and is a nice point of API design.

Comment: @pfctdayelise What I mean is that if you are dealing with mutable data the user will expect the constructor to copy it. E.g. `t = [1,2,3]; s = list(t); s.append(4) -> also t gets modified... WTF!?!`. However if the data is immutable (like `tuple`s) this isn't a problem since the user cannot operate on the data in a way that changes unexpectedly other objects.